# css to visualize that element is clickable (like a tab)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the user to see that the text is clickable. As of now I have changed cursor to a pointer, and added an underline to the text on the `<span>` element, I have also tried different borders and highlights on text (basically changed colors), but I was unable to make that look good.

I am using `panel panel-primary` from [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels), and I know they have have a Tabs component also, but I can not use that due to other reasons.

[Simple plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/75TwPyouXu66DcOANVwm?p=preview)

```
<div class="panel panel-primary" >
    <div class="panel-heading"> SomeHeading <span style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer" >Tab1</span> <span style="font-size: 8px;" class="badge">1</span> / <span style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer">Tab2</span> <span style="font-size: 8px;" class="badge">3</span> 
</div> 

<div class="panel-body">
  Some content here
</div>
```

What more can I do to make the user understand that these are actually tabs?

Comment: You should use bootstrap tabs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the user to see that the text is clickable. As of now I have
>   changed cursor to a pointer, and added an underline to the text on the
>   element.

These are both pretty standard conventions. Other visual cues (usually activated on `:hover`) might include:

- bolding the text with `font-weight:bold`
- changing the `color` of the text
- changing the `background-color` of the text
- changing the `border` of the text

You might even:

- give the text a `text-shadow`
- give the text's containing element a `box-shadow`

Comment: I can see what of these I can use when element is hoovered (is that word?). But that requires the user the actually hoover them (not sure they will do that if they don't already know they are tabs)

Comment: Yes - you can add a sprinkling of visual cues before the `:hover` applies and a few more visual cues on `:hover` to confirm that the visitor is on the right track. Usually `font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; cursor:pointer;` is enough of a visual cue to pick the text out as a link before adding extra visual cues on `:hover`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [what Rounin said,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812744/3842050) you could also add a [border](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp):

```
border-style: groove; border-color: #3377ff;
```

See the new [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/qbTd0dYiOjttlcbchPl8?p=preview).

EDIT: I realized he also mentioned borders.

Comment: thanks, I will probably use some sort of border (just has to find the correct color/size)